# Creating a real photo album - need a recommendation for an app to create family photo albums

Tags: images, photography, printing

I have been creating my last two family photo albums in a crappy album creator application (tied to the print house).
I really need to switch to something easier. My requirements are not that high. In terms of quality, it has to be good (not marriage album level) and to be able to order the result on thick pages. But I want the user experience to be excellent - Saving arrangement templates, auto placement of pictures.
And I want to be able to send the result for printing.
I want to to learn about your experience with creating family albums software.
Thanks.

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: And should it be free, or do you have a budegt in mind?

Answer (score 1):

For a family vacation in 2003, I used my usual thumnail and image file management program (ThumbsPlus, if you care, but I'm not here to recommend a product but describe an approach to this problem) to print all the pictures, 4-up on a page, with ID numbers.  The quarter-page was just a little smaller than the normal print, and I could take care of a small number of featured photos separately.

It automatically and trivially generated album pages, which I then put in plastic page protectors in a 3-ring binder.

That's as easy as it gets! Uniform filled pages, not faux-scrapbook. There's a button for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know I am just starting to use Light Room 5 to create a photo book. If I remember correctly, the photo book creation was added to Light Room starting with version 4, so if you have Light Room software, it has to version 4 or 5.

It has really good options and lets you upload to Blub.com for printing - this is what I've read in the help file, I have not yet uploaded as I am still working on my book - and it also allows you to save as a .pdf or .jpg; again, from the help file.